# 8086 assembly - sign and overflow flags

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I'm currently learning 8086 assembly and I understand the difference between sign and overflow flags but I can't think of an example when only one of them is turned on. Can you give me an example? Please try to use the simplest commands you can so I could understand the example.

Comment: See http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt to learn about OF vs. CF (I think it mentions SF)

Answer (score 1):

x86's `neg` instruction sets flags based on `0 - input`.

```
.model small
.data
.code

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov al, 6
    neg al       ; this will set sign flag but not overflow flag ( NEG instruction is used to find 2's complement of some number )      

    mov al, -127        
    sub al, 127  ; this will set overflow flag but not sign flag: -127 - 127 = +2

    mov al, -128
    neg al       ; this sets both OF and SF: 0 - 128 overflow to -128

    mov ah, 04ch   
    int 21h      ; exit(al)

end
```

Tested in emu8086.

Note that `0-128` overflow to -128.  (The [2's complement special case of the most negative number being its own absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Most_negative_number)).  The largest 8-bit 2's complement integer is +127.